# Using R in Python with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, sunburnt

I currently have an R code that works very well and i want to use rpy2 package to use this code in python.

The code show a Sunburst in R:

```
library(sunburstR)

sequences <- read.csv(system.file("examples/visitsequences.csv",package="sunburstR"),header=F,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sunburst(sequences)
```

But in Python, when i use rpy2 i have this :

```
sequences = r('read.csv(system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",package="sunburstR"),header=F,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)')
r('sunburst(sequences)')
```

In fact, it works but it doesnt show the chart ...

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Your question, as it is, is too broad to get any useful answer. Please edit it and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also,  please do not show your code as an image. No one wants to type it all in again.  Instead, paste the code into your question.

Comment: ok i didnt know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use:

```
 r('sun <- sunburst(sequences); print(sun)')
```